# Passing "this" and "event" in JS function

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, this

I have a button with an onclick event as follows:

```
<button type="button" onclick="captions(event)">
     <img src="someimg.png">
</button>
```

I need to be able to change the img src without using an ID to reference it.  I want to pass "this" and the event (I need to do some other things that require event to be passed) but I cannot get this to work.  Example of JS is below:

```
function captions(event) {
             this.src = this.src.replace("img2.png");
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is `this.src.replace("img2.png")` supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest *not* using inline event handlers.  You should bind the event "unobtrusively" using JavaScript.

First give the button a class:

```
<button type="button" class="captions">
     <img src="someimg.png">
</button>
```

Then bind the event:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var captions = document.getElementsByClassName('captions');
    for(var i = 0, len = captions.length; i < len; i++){
        captions[i].addEventListener('click', function(event){
            // this is your button, what you clicked on
            // you need to get the image
            var image = this.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];

            // this.src.replace("img2.png") doesn't do what you think it does
            // String.replace takes 2 parameters
            image.src = '/your/new/image';
        });
    }
};
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/WcFzq/

Answer (score 1):

You can get the element that was clicked using the event.target property (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_target.asp).

```
function captions(event) {
         event.target.src = "img2.png";
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hammerhito/Y75VP/1/).

Comment: Careful with this . . . older versions of IE (IE8 and earlier) use `event.srcElement`, instead of `event.target`.

Comment: This might work, but `event.target` might not *always* be the `<img>`.

Comment: Depending on the context, the actual image tag may need to be gotten with `target`, `srcElement` or `currentTarget`.  `currentTarget` is likely better as it always gives the element that had the handler attached to it.  The main idea is to grab the info from the event object.

Answer (score 0):

Following will solve your problem.

```
function captions(event) {
   var img = this.childNodes[0];
   img.src = img.src.replace("img2.png");
}
```

Comment: But, he still needs to get `this` inside the `captions` function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do an inline `onclick` event, you should simply be able to pass a new variable that captures the element into the function, like this:

```
function captions(element, event) {
    . . . do stuff . . .
}
```

Then you would call it, passing `this` in for the `element` parameter, like this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="captions(this, event);">
    <img src="someimg.png">
</button>
```